# How to set margins on each side for TabLayout

Tags: java, android

Just so this question is not misunderstood, I do not mean margins for individual tabs. I mean a space before the first tab and a space after the last tab.

The appearance i am trying to achieve is one of a centered selected tab at all times such as this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TabLayout` from the support library, then I think you can do this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ...
    app:tabPaddingStart="50dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="50dp">
```

Comment: doesn't work. it creates a space in front of the first tab but shifts the rest of the tabs to the right and leaves no space at the last tab.